# how can I read from a file and append each word to a dictionary?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

what I want to do is read from a file, and then for each word, append it to a dictionary along with its number of occurances.

example:

'today is sunday. tomorrow is not sunday.'

my dictionary would then be this:
{'today': 1, 'is': 2, 'sunday': 2, 'tomorrow': 1, 'not': 1}

the way I'm going about it is to use readline and split to create a list, and then append each element and it's value to an empty dictionary, but it's not really working so far. here's what I have so far, although its incomplete:

```
file = open('any_file,txt', 'r')

for line in file.readline().split():
     for i in range(len(line)):
         new_dict[i] = line.count(i)  # I'm getting an error here as well, saying that  
return new_dict                       # I can't convert int to str implicitly
```

the problem with this is that when my dictionary updates when each line is read, the value of a word won't accumulate. so if in another line 'sunday' occurred 3 times, my dictionary would contain {'sunday': 3} instead of {'sunday': 5}. any help? I have no idea where to go from here and I'm new to all of this.

Comment: Another problem is that if "sunday" occurs 3 times on a line, you are doing `line.count("sunday")` 3 times which is wasteful

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

e.g:

```
from itertools import chain

with open("file.txt") as file:
    Counter(chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in file))
```

(Using a [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) too.)

Note that your example only works on the first line, I presume this wasn't intentional, and this solution is for across the whole file (obviously it's trivial to swap that around).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple version that doesn't deal with punctuation

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
with open('any_file,txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            counter[word] += 1
```

can also be written like this:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(word for line in file for word in line.split())
```

Here's one way to solve the problem using a `dict`

```
counter = {}
with open('any_file,txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            if word not in counter:
                counter[word] = 1
            else:
                counter[word] += 1
```

Comment: This kind of defies the point of using a `collections.Counter()`. (Edit: with the edit it's a little better, although it's an inefficient way to flatten an iterable).

Comment: is collection counter the only way to do this? I'm assuming any other solution would just be long and tedious though

Comment: @peppy Of course it's not the only solution, but it's efficient and the work is done for you.

Comment: @peppy, you can do it with a `dict` you just need to add the key if it is not there, and add 1 to the value

Comment: @Peppy. I added a version using a dict. There are other ways but I think this one is simple to understand.

Comment: @peppy Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) that helped you the most, and upvote any answers that helped you. That's the best way to say thank you on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Python 3 or Python 2.7?

If yes, use Counter from collections library:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
words = re.findall('\w+', open('any_file.txt').read().lower())
Counter(words).most_common(10)
```

But you get list of tuples though. It should be easy for you to turn list of tuples to dictionary.

Comment: This regex isn't really needed, and `collections` exists in 2.x.

Comment: @Lattyware, sorry I should have made myself clearer. The Counter is not available in python 2.

Comment: I just tested, it's definitely there in at least 2.7.

Comment: @Lattyware, sorry, I just realized I used python 2.6. The Counter was introduced in python 2.7. http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 file = open('any_file.txt', 'r')
 myDict = {}
 for line in file:
     lineSplit = line.split(" ")
     for x in xrange(len(lineSplit)):
         if lineSplit[x] in myDict.keys(): myDict[lineSplit[x]] += 1
         else: myDict[lineSplit[x]] = 1

 file.close()

 print myDict
```